# Route [password.request] not defined. But Auth is in routing [laravel]

Tags: laravel, view, routes, laravel-blade

My project crashes on login screen. It tries to get password.request route which it does not see. In routing, there is of course

```
Auth::routes();
```

but I did add some other stuff that uses authentication mechanisms. I copied remember password views and controllers from vendors and renamed them to reuse for other purposes.

To be honest I don't even know how to debug missing route. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to copy views and controllers from the vendors folder manually if you're doing things with Laravel. Instead run `php artisan make:auth` in a console. This command will copy the necessary auth blade templates and update your `routes/web.php` to suit. There is some more info here [in the official docs on Laravel authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication).

Also, if you haven't already, you'll need to run migrations by running `php artisan migrate` in a console. This will create the `users` and `password_resets` tables needed to allow registration, login and password recovery.

If you're still having trouble and want to debug things more, make sure you set `APP_DEBUG=true` inside your `.env` file in the projects root path. This should record a stack trace in storage/logs/laravel.log when an error occurs.

Comment: I am using already the laravel auth. I was copying to make similar mechanism IN ADDITION to the basic auth. But I'm using only pasword reset classes.